# Remove class after click outside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I know this is a old question , but i've searched a lot .
i want to remove class after clicked outside the like body .  here is my code :
**Html**

```
   <div id="user-login-top">Enter</div>
   <div id="user-login-wrapper" class="">visible</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#user-login-top").on("click", function () {
        $("#user-login-wrapper").addClass("wide");
    });
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is("#user-login-wrapper") === false) {
            $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/7f32byhn/)

Appreciate your help !?
Thx

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/7f32byhn/2/

Comment: thx @MohitArora it worked , you should answer it , and i'll hook u up ;)

Comment: acceted answer also good :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is because of the propagation of event.

When you click on `user-login-top`, the first click handle is triggered which is adding the class, then because of event propagation the handler attached to the document is triggered where it satisfies the if condition and removes the class.

One possible solution here is to use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#user-login-top").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#user-login-wrapper").addClass("wide");
    e.stopPropagation()
  });
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("#user-login-wrapper") === false) {
      $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#user-login-wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
}
#user-login-wrapper.wide {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-login-top">ورود</div>
<div id="user-login-wrapper" class="">visible</div>
```

---

Another is

```js
$(function() {
  $("#user-login-top").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#user-login-wrapper").toggleClass("wide");
  });
  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("#user-login-wrapper, #user-login-top") === false) {
      $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#user-login-wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
}
#user-login-wrapper.wide {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user-login-top">ورود</div>
<div id="user-login-wrapper" class="">visible</div>
```

Comment: For my case it worked only if I set the event on the first click to stopPropagation() otherwise it did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
  <div class="click-text">
    click inside and outside me
  </div>
</section>


const concernedElement = document.querySelector(".click-text");
document.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
  if (concernedElement.contains(event.target)) {
    console.log("Clicked Inside");
  } else {
    console.log("Clicked Outside / Elsewhere");
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).